# How to hide parent window menu bar when child window is active?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms. I have created a menu bar in main window and set `IsMdicontainer= true`. In second window I have created menu bar and set `windowstate is maximize`.

My problem is that when the child window is active, the parent window menu bar is also showing with the child window menu. I need to hide the parent window menu bar and only show it once the child window is closed.

Comment: Please always provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. In addition, describe what you already tried.

Comment: It seems you have tried to post a picture but do not have sufficient reputation for that.

Comment: yes... i was tried..

Comment: You will have to set Visibilty of the menu bar to false whenever the second window is opened and to true as soon as it is closed.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? It's not standard behaviour for MDI applications.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you open the child form from this menu, then you could use the `MdiChildActivate` event handler from the `ParentForm`.
This works even with more than one subform.

```
    private void ParentForm_MdiChildActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = Application.OpenForms.
                                Cast<Form>().
                                Count(x => x.IsMdiChild);

        // The menu will be displayed again only if all subforms are closed
        parentFormMenu.Visible = (count <= 0);
    }
```